# Why might packaged pineapple contain egg, soy, peanut, fish, milk, sulphites, tree nuts, sesame, crustaceans, shellfish, mustard seeds, wheat?

Tags: shopping, pineapple

Here is the proof:

[image]

I'm a bit scared to eat it. What do they do to it?!

Comment: From your question title I thought it was a whole pineapple! I was thinking maybe it's grown on the same tree as chickens, soy beans, peanuts, fish, cows, etc.!

Comment: May also contain Fruit Bat, Albatross, and Spam.

Comment: Also spam, spam, spam, and spam.

Comment: Even though this question made me laughing a bit, it is after all a low quality question in meaning, that answer to it is so obvious. Also, keep in mind, that you're telling us today, that you're scared to eat a pineapple, that has **expiry date of 15 JUN 2007**. It is exactly **eight years old**. I would be very scared to eat eight years old pineapple, even if it wouldn't contain a shellfish, chicken and mustard!

Comment: @trejder I think the date is in YY/MMM/DD format, which gives 2015 June 07.

Comment: @zovits Well... quite confusing. Never got used to this "short years", especially _after_ Y2K! :>

Comment: "contain a shellfish" ... or spongebob :) that said, some delicious pineapple curries have plenty of mustard seeds in them ;)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Although it doesn't explicitly say so, that's allergy information. It's just been processed in a place that also (potentially) processes those things, so it potentially contains a trace amount, which could be bad if you have a really sensitive allergy. It won't contain enough of those things to matter for any other purpose.

Often labels like that are written along the lines of "processed in a facility which also processes..." to make it a little more clear. The lists aren't usually that long, either; most facilities don't process *everything*. But as pointed out in the comments, a grocery store is a lot more likely to just have a single kitchen that possibly handles all kinds of things.

Comment: @ermanen - This is especially common in bulk packaging as a kind of catch-all, especially if packaged at a grocery store that produces/sells a variety of prepared foods. However, this list is far more extensive than I've ever seen!

Comment: It might mean they're being extra conscientious! Or it might mean "we don't trust our dishwashers and cleaning staff"

Comment: This is common amongst companies that don't want to take on the liability for downstream resellers who demand certain conditions. It's easier and cheaper to deliver product that leaves all risk with the consumer.

Comment: The sad part about this is that it essentially undermines the intent of the labeling.  If you just put every allergen on the label to prevent liability, you might as well not put any on there at all and just say don't buy our stuff if you have a food allergy.

Comment: This specific case isn't really about liability for resellers; the label is from a grocery store. It seems fair for them to say, well, maybe sometimes we're going to have pecan-crusted fish, sesame-soy shrimp, etc at the prepared food bar, let's just make sure. Otherwise they have to keep really careful track of everything they ever prepare.

Comment: This looks like it was printed out on a scale. Usually there will be a label template in addition to the fields that update for the item being printed. They probably just put allergens in the template so they don't have to update it for each product as a lazy/CYA move.

Answer (score 4):

If this was processed at the store then there's a pretty good chance they process everything in close quarters where there is a reasonable chance it was packaged alongside some of the other store-packaged products that could contain some of these other things. I definitely would not expect fresh pineapple to include shellfish.

Comment: "_I definitely would not expect fresh pineapple to include shellfish_" just made my day! LOL! :> Thanks! :>

Answer (score 2):

Haha, that's hilarious.

I suspect it's a catch-all legal disclaimer.  Put "may spawn bank-robbing zombies" on all your food labels and no one can ever sue you when your zombies rob their bank accounts.

It's really frustrating for people with food allergies: They have to avoid all foods with half-assed legal disclaimers instead of just foods that to actually contain the allergen.

Comment: To be fair, if your allergy is that severe, you already have to avoid anything coming out of an unknown kitchen like this grocery store one, right? Most things like this don't even *have* labels, you just know it was made in the kitchen in the back, pretty much like at a restaurant, and anything else they prepare/serve could potentially have contaminated it.

Comment: Mostly true. Those with not-gonna-kill-ya allergies are more relaxed, but would still like good information.